# To the back of whom?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

In Parashat Vayeira Lot is instructed ([Bereishit 19:17](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8214#showrashi=true&v=17)) ''אל תביט אחריך'' not to look to the back of him while Sodom is getting hit. It turns out that Lot's wife looks back and turns into a pillar of salt.

The question is why when the Posuk ([Bereishit 19:26](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8214#showrashi=true&v=26)) says that she looked back it says ותבט אשתו מאחריו meaning she looked to the back of him rather than ותבט אשתו מאחריה which would mean that she looked to the back of herself (as if the Issur was for her to look to the back of him rather than to her own back which is difficult to understand)?

Answer (score 2):

Rashi, Ibn Ezra, and the Rambam on the verse say that she looked behind Lot. [The Ramban explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.26?lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=bi) that Lot was bringing up the rear, so she looked past him to see the destruction.

Comment: Alshich says it is referring to G-d: https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.19.26?lang=bi&with=Alshich&lang2=en . Rabbeinu Bechaya says it referring to the angel of destruction